# Wrong characters on editing HTML under eclipse Helios with PDT after php tags

Tags: php, html, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

Maybe the title of my question is not very correct, i'm very sorry.

I have Windows 7 x64 with eclipse helios + PDT 3.0.0v20110516. I've created a php file with this content:

```
<?php if (count($travels)):?>
<ul class="real-height ribbon-m " id="travels">
  <?php foreach($travels as $travel):?>
  <li class="message t-ruler fitted ribbon-l">
```

all code is highlighted correctly, but if I try to insert new html or php tags after `?>` my editor gets crazy, it types anything in the correct or any other lines, so I can't add new php code.

Does anybody know how to solve it?

Thank you very much

Comment: Not sure if you mean that the example you gave is highlighted correctly or not. Could you give an example of code that's not highlighted correctly? Also, it's good practice to put at least one space before the ending `?>`.

Answer (score 0):

This is called [alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php): You still need to end each statement:

```
<?php if (count($travels)>=1):?>
    <ul class="real-height ribbon-m " id="travels">

    <?php foreach($travels as $travel):?>
      <li class="message t-ruler fitted ribbon-l">

    <?php endforeach;?>

<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
<?php if (count($travels)):?>
<ul class="real-height ribbon-m " id="travels">
  <?php foreach($travels as $travel):?>
  <li class="message t-ruler fitted ribbon-l"> <?php echo $travel;?></li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

if you are already doing this try to post what exactly are the tags you are writing.

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to the following annoying Eclipse bug:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=359473